# Flexible File Task - SSIS - Unable to delete from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, etl

I am able to copy files from an azure blob storage account not problem however once downloaded I want to delete them from storage.

Whenever I setup a flexible file task and set delete I get the the following error:

'SourceFolderPath' is not specified. I set this as a variable within the flexible file task and then try to re-run but then receive an error 'specified folderPath' does not exist.

Whatever combination I try I am unable to get this to work.

Anyone had a similar issue with SSIS ?

For something that should be so simple I am unable to get this to work.

I am able to copy files from an azure blob storage account not problem however once downloaded I want to delete them from storage.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you are setting up the flexible file task and the variable for the `SourceFolderPath`? Also, have you checked if the specified folder path actually exists in the Blob Storage?

Comment: Hi Aswin - when i use the 'copy' operation I use a SourceFolderPath 'broadbean/' which works and copies from the storage across to a local file.

However if i set this up the same way as a 'delete' operation the SSIS package fails.

Comment: While deleting,it requires the full file path.

Comment: So as in /*blobstoragename*/broadbean/ ?

Comment: Can you give filename and check?

Comment: Hi Aswin , i have added a image of how i have the flexible file task setup - i have included the full folder path and file name and still getting the same error 'SourceFolderPath' is not specified. Whenever i try and add this as an expression i still seem to get a failure.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For a delete, do not use `sourcefilename` and `sourcefolderpath`.  Instead, use `filename` and `folderpath`.
The expression for the `folderpath` must be followed by a `/`.

[image: Expression Editor]